# Gnuplot to properly output an image via script

Tags: batch-file, gnuplot

I've created a script:

```
f(x,y) = -(y+47)*sin(sqrt(abs(x/2+y+47)))-x*sin(sqrt(abs(x-y-47)))
set xrange[-512:512]
set yrange[-512:512]
set isosamples 100
unset key
set view 35,37
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font 'Helvetica,10'
set output 'image.eps'
```

However when I run the command: `gnuplot filename` it creates an image named image.eps, but is just white. How can I get the image of the graph?

Thanks.

Comment: You must  `splot` your function with `splot f(x,y)` as last step

Comment: If you want to supply that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do the actual plotting with `plot` for 2D or, like in your case, with `splot` for 3D. Note, that the plotting must be done only after all `set` commands:

```
set terminal ...
set output ...
set ...
splot x**2 + y**2
```